# onClick with Bootstrap is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to achieve that after a click on a button (Bootstrap 3.3.7.1) it is marked as active. For that I actually just copy paste a code I found here on stackoverflow. But still, when I test it, the button doesn't show any behavior.

Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="template :: head">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="specifyDetails">
        <h2>Chose what you want to trade</h2>
        <label>
            <select th:name="Products" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple">
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="productList" type="java.util.List"*/-->
                <option th:each="product : ${productList}"><a th:text="${product}"></a></option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <button th:type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
    </form>
    <form><a th:href="'orderview/'" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button">Orderview only</a>
    </form>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Input Button"/>

    <script>$('.btn-info').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })</script>
</div>


<div th:replace="template :: footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here the **template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="head">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <!--/*@thymesVar id="title" type="String"*/-->
    <title th:text="${title}">Library trader</title>
</head>

<footer th:fragment="footer">
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js}"></script>

    <link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</footer>
</html>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Check if there's any error message in the browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `click` event handler in the footer because you are loading `jquery` after loading DOM

in footer

like

```
<footer th:fragment="footer">
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js}"></script>
    <script>$('.btn-info').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).addClass('active');
        })</script>

    //rest of the code
</footer>
```

Comment: that works! But now I have the problem that every button on every other html page with that footer uses that script. And buttons which should actually make use of href are no longer working refering to another page, they are just active. So how can I make your code only usuable in that specific html file?

Answer (score 0):

Add the ready function to your script :

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.btn-info').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this the issue. You are finding the element with `btn-info` CSS Class.

Since there are two elements with the same CSS class name, it's failing to apply on-click event to each element.

So below code works as I'm iterating the `$('.btn-info')` so that every button with the class has on-click event.

```js
/*$('.btn-info').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })*/

$('.btn-info').each(function( index ) {
  $(this).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('active');
        alert("class Added")
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="template :: head">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="specifyDetails">
        <h2>Chose what you want to trade</h2>
        <label>
            <select th:name="Products" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple">
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="productList" type="java.util.List"*/-->
                <option th:each="product : ${productList}"><a th:text="${product}"></a></option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <button th:type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
    </form>
    <form><a th:href="'orderview/'" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button">Orderview only</a>
    </form>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Input Button"/>

</div>


<div th:replace="template :: footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this might help. Thank you!!